# External javascript file won't load with new code added

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, wordpress-theming

I have a strange problem. I'm building a mobile Wordpress theme using jQuery, jQuery Mobile and my own external .js file. I've used `<?php global $post; $post_slug=$post->post_name; echo $post_slug; ?>` to get the page slug title and insert it as the id on the body tag. Now I want to have a certain piece of html inserted into the theme at a specific point if a certain page is loaded. Now the immediate problem is that I can't even test my code because for some reason, my .js file will not even load if I include this one new function. Here is the file:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $("#menu_img").click(function () {
    $menu_img = $(this);
    $nav_slider = $menu_img.next();
    $nav_slider.slideToggle(500); 
    });
});

$(document ).on("mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#send_button").click(function() {
        $("#tea_form").submit();
    });
});

/*$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("body").hasId("roncy-report") === true) {
        $("div#menu").after('<div id="roncy_head">
                                    <img id="roncy_img" src="http://trustrealtygroup.ca/wp-content/themes/trg_mobile/images/roncy_banner.png" alt="">
                                  </div>')};

});*/
```

The file loads fine if I comment out that last bit but will not load if it is uncommented. What could cause this??

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, jQuery doesn't have a `.hasId()` method, and JS balks on strings separated on different lines like you have.

To test for Id, you can just use a straight selector like `$("#roncy-report")`.

Updated last bit of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($("#roncy-report").length) {
        $("div#menu").after('<div id="roncy_head"><img id="roncy_img" src="http://trustrealtygroup.ca/wp-content/themes/trg_mobile/images/roncy_banner.png" alt=""></div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: Ok, well that got the file to load but its adding the html snippet on every page. Not just the one with the specified id.